# iphone xmppframework How do I list all the online users of my particular domain

Tags: iphone, xmppframework

I am using xmppframework for iPhone. I want to know how can I check all the available users of my particular domain?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceivePresence:(XMPPPresence *)presence {

    NSString *presenceType = [presence type]; // online/offline
    NSString *myUsername = [[sender myJID] user];
    NSString *presenceFromUser = [[presence from] user];


    if (![presenceFromUser isEqualToString:myUsername]) {

        if ([presenceType isEqualToString:@"available"]) {
            [_chatDelegate newBuddyOnline:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@", presenceFromUser, @"gmail.com"]];

        } else if ([presenceType isEqualToString:@"unavailable"]) {

            [_chatDelegate buddyWentOffline:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@", presenceFromUser, @"gmail.com"]];

        }

    }
}
```

USE this method to AppDelegate file.

In this create @protocol with newBuddyOnline method.

And where you want to show the list, you just use these method in that,..

```
- (void)newBuddyOnline:(NSString *)buddyName {

    [onlineBuddies addObject:buddyName];
    [self.TableView reloadData];
}

- (void)buddyWentOffline:(NSString *)buddyName {
    [onlineBuddies removeObject:buddyName];
    [self.TableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: How to get above response? means what should i request to server to server send me the list of my friends with status.

Comment: the above shows me the presence of current loggin user and does not show the presence of other resistered users

Comment: @Suresh.D how can i call those two methods from delegate?

Comment: NSObject may not responds to newBuddyOnline. am getting this warning and my newBuddyOnline is not calling.how should i call newBuddyOnline method from Appdelegate

Comment: @Sushrita it is protocol, where ever you are implementing you should use that.